# Mysqli num_rows( ) returning undefined property

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to count up the amount of registered users in my database however, I am having a problem with the num_rows.. as its giving an error.

Here is my index.php code:

```
<?php
require 'connections.php';
$con->query("SELECT users, UserID from users");
$totalplayers = $con->num_rows;
?>
```

Here is my connections.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "website");

if (isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
    $result = $con->query("select * from users where UserID=".$_SESSION['UserID']);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

However, it is giving this error and I have no clue what to do!:

> Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$num_rows in C:....\index.php
>   on line 4

Comment: `$con` is a http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php, `Returns an object which represents the connection to a MySQL Server.`, not the result of your query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should assign the result of the query and then get the count :

```
<?php
require 'connections.php';
$result = $con->query("SELECT users, UserID from users");
// $result is a mysqli_stmt
$totalplayers = $result->num_rows;
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: Thankyou, this worked ( I had to change the actual query still as I typed it wrong)